# Continuously getting data from heart rate monitor

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp

I've been working on a project that reads a person's heart rate from a Polar H7 hrm. I've been successful in connecting the device and getting the heart rate which the program shows as text in the UI. However, there are instances where the program suddenly stops getting input from the device.

I have already checked the connection of the device to my Win 10 laptop and saw that it was stable, there were also no exceptions getting thrown by the program. The text simply stops changing.

Here is the code I've written:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{   
    private GattDeviceService device;


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        init();
    }

    async void init()
    {
        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.HeartRate));
        Status.Text = devices.Count.ToString();
        device = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id);
        enableSensor();
    }

    private async void enableSensor()
    {
        IReadOnlyList<GattCharacteristic> characteristicList;

        characteristicList = device.GetAllCharacteristics();
        if (characteristicList != null)
        {
            GattCharacteristic characteristic = characteristicList[0];
            if (characteristic.CharacteristicProperties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
            {
                characteristic.ValueChanged += SendNotif;
                await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
            }
        }
    }

    async void SendNotif(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.CharacteristicValue.Length != 0) { 
            byte[] hrData = new byte[eventArgs.CharacteristicValue.Length];
            DataReader.FromBuffer(eventArgs.CharacteristicValue).ReadBytes(hrData);

            var hrValue = ProcessData(hrData);


            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Status.Text = hrValue.ToString();

            });
        }

    }

    private int ProcessData(byte[] data)
    {
        // Heart Rate profile defined flag values
        const byte heartRateValueFormat = 0x01;

        byte currentOffset = 0;
        byte flags = data[currentOffset];
        bool isHeartRateValueSizeLong = ((flags & heartRateValueFormat) != 0);

        currentOffset++;

        ushort heartRateMeasurementValue;

        if (isHeartRateValueSizeLong)
        {
            heartRateMeasurementValue = (ushort)((data[currentOffset + 1] << 8) + data[currentOffset]);
            currentOffset += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            heartRateMeasurementValue = data[currentOffset];
        }

        return heartRateMeasurementValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Retrieving data from a heart rate sensor is NOT a concern of the UI. Restructure your code, and then things can become clearer where to find the source of the issues. Btw, can you exclude a "stable" heart rate?

Comment: `private async void enableSensor()` since `enableSensor` is not an event handler, it should be `async Task` instead of `async void`.